# 2 files with same hash, but 1 is corrupted and 1 isn't

Tags: hash, gis, sha256, qgis

I found something very weird on a project.
I have 2 files :

- One is the input file, it's a .bip file which you can open with GIS software like QGIS
  [here's the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHBCV.jpg). this file is provided by the CCSDS and accessible [here](https://cwe.ccsds.org/sls/docs/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsls%2Fdocs%2FSLS%2DDC%2F123%2E0%2DB%2DInfo%2FTestData%2FTestPattern&FolderCTID=0x012000439B56FF51847E41B5728F9730D7B55F&View=%7BAE8FB44C%2DE80A%2D42CF%2D8558%2DFB495ABB675F%7D)
- The other is the output after been compressed and decompressed by a lossless compression algorithm (CCSDS 123 by ESA)

Those 2 files shares the exact same sha256 and sha1 hash, so they are identical.
`3226009de97d66589fc58cdc9af377e6315ccc69a7095bec8dc04447bf3cea2e  test_ptn_x100y36z17_16u.bip`
`3226009de97d66589fc58cdc9af377e6315ccc69a7095bec8dc04447bf3cea2e  test_ptn_decomp.bip` (sha256 shown here).

The thing is, if the entry is showed by QGIS, the second one displays a message and refuses to open [it shows this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl9Az.png) *(translated : the file test_ptn_decomp.bip is not a recognized or valid data source)*

Is there something i don't understand with hashes ? i've tried moving files to other directories and renaming but nothing changes QGIS wise.

Comment: Do they have the same EXIF info?

Comment: Having same hash doesn't mean they are identical (it is much quick to check if files are identical than to calculate hashes). In any case: you should copy in the answer the error message (please do not use a figure). Could you check the permission of the file?

Comment: Hi @Olha, they don't as this is not strictly speaking image files, it's not a jpeg. It multispectral images (more "layers" than RGB). .bip doesn't contain exif as i understand it. I have trouble finding informations about this file format.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi sure, they are similar : `-rwxrwxrwx 1 sytrics sytrics 122400 May  4 10:08 test_ptn_decomp.bip`

Comment: In any case, I think you are in the wrong site: this is about programming. Possibly the sister site about gis (look the links on top right icon, for the list of our sister sites). [I'll not be surprised that the error message is unrelated to the real errors).

Comment: indeed i also feel like its GIS software related. Anyway thanks for the advice and i will make sure to use less images from now on :)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi - If two different inputs produce the same hash, that's called a collision.  Collisions have been found with older hashing algorithms, such as MD5.  But, to date, no collisions have been found with SHA256 (see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet).  So, if two files produce the same SHA256 hash, it's *highly* unlikely that they are non-identical files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly unlikely you got a different content with same sha256 hash by chance. So I'll assume the files are identical. Anyway, it is easy to use any diff program to compare.

So there should be some other differences, things that come to mind:

1. file name might contain some meaningful information needed by QGIS. Try renaming decompressed file e.g. decomp_ptn_x100y36z17_16u.bip, maybe x100..  is essential?
2. There are some additional files, that must have matching names. Do you have a .hdr file, as explained in QGIS tutorials?
   https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/open_bil_bip_bsq_files.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, indeed there is a header file in the inputn but NOT for the output. i didn't notice it but it could in fact be the culprit !

Comment: and i checked and it was in fact the header file that was missing ! Thank you Michael !

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted, it helps stackoverflow users finds the right answers.